# Detect when 2 buttons are being pushed simultaneously without reacting to when the first button is pushed

Tags: c++, robotics

I'm programming a robot's controller logic. On the controller there is 2 buttons. There is 3 different actions tied to 2 buttons, one occurs when only the first button is being pushed, the second when only the second is pushed, and the third when both are being pushed.

Normally when the user means to hit both buttons they would hit one after another. This has the consequence of executing a incorrect action.

Here is part of the code.

```cpp
while (true)
{
    conveyor_mtr.setVelocity(22, pct);

    if (Controller1.ButtonL2.pressing() && Controller1.ButtonL1.pressing())
    {
      conveyor_mtr.spin(fwd); // action 1
    }
    else if (Controller1.ButtonL2.pressing())
    {
      backGoalLift.setAngle(3); // action 2
    }
    
    else if (Controller1.ButtonL1.pressing())
    {
      backGoalLift.setAngle(55); // action 3
    }
    else
    {
      conveyor_mtr.stop(hold);
    }
    task::sleep(20); //ms
}
```

Comment: The term you're looking for is "debouncing"

Comment: You need to delay the single button press event to allow the correct assessment of the desired command. Since you have a *sleep* (which I don't recommend, better schedule the task execution) you can do it with a counter to wait few hundreds of milliseconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a short timer, which is restarted every time a button press is triggered. Every time the timer expires, you check all currently pressed buttons. Of course, you will need to select a good timer duration to make it possible to press two buttons "simultaneously" while keeping your application feel responsive.

You can implement a simple timer using a counter in your loop. However, at some point you will be happier with an event based architecture.